# set OnItemClickListener to Navigation Drawer's ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I came across an online example which demonstrated building a Navigation Drawer without implementing changing of `Fragment`(s). I tried adding this but got no success so far. The tutorial used a `ListView` and a custom adapter.

*Here is what I have so far:*

**Activity**

```
public class NavigationMain extends AppCompatActivity  {


private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
// private ImageView mImageView;
ImageView banar1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

private static String TAG = NavigationMain.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_creative_navigation);

    String[] web = NavigationMain.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);


    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.profile,
            R.drawable.photo,
            R.drawable.message,
            R.drawable.event,
    };



    Typeface fonts1;
    fonts1 =  Typeface.createFromAsset(NavigationMain.this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");


    TextView fullname =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    TextView schoolname =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.schoolname);
    TextView logout =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    TextView txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView txt1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    TextView txt2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    TextView txt3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    fullname.setTypeface(fonts1);
    schoolname.setTypeface(fonts1);
    logout.setTypeface(fonts1);
    txt.setTypeface(fonts1);
    txt1.setTypeface(fonts1);
    txt2.setTypeface(fonts1);
    txt3.setTypeface(fonts1);

    CustomList adapter1 = new
            CustomList(NavigationMain.this, web, imageId);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter1);

    final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { //pick from file
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    } );

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
   banar1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banar1);
    banar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            dialog.show();

        }
    });



    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                banar1.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

            if (f.exists()) f.delete();

            break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                    startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            } );

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.nav_drawer_row, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        Typeface fonts;
        fonts =  Typeface.createFromAsset(NavigationMain.this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");


        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);





        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        txtTitle.setTypeface(fonts);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}

}
```

**NavigationDrawerAdapter**

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<NavDrawerItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

public void delete(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
}
```

**FragmentDrawer**

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

// private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
private View containerView;
private static String[] titles = null;
private static String[] titles1 = null;
private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

public FragmentDrawer() {

}

public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
    this.drawerListener = listener;
}

public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_home,
            R.drawable.ic_tv,
            R.drawable.ic_ticket,
            R.drawable.ic_offers,
            R.drawable.ic_earning,
            R.drawable.ic_usemoney,
            R.drawable.ic_ranking,
            R.drawable.ic_faq,
            R.drawable.ic_faq

    };

    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);




}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
   // recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
  /*  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
*/
    return layout;
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }


}

public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_creative_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.umateapp.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
</fragment>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, the `RecyclerView` method was commented out and the tutor used `ListView` instead. I tried removing the `ListView` and using the `RecyclerView`, but I ran into problems.

Comment: Take a look here.. i think has what you are looking for... http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: What do you mean with problems? It's compiling?  Do you have an exception? What kind of and where? Please add more details.

Comment: @NikosMitropoulos Thanks so much. I have another problem this line in the NavigationDrawerAdapter `holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());` is giving me a NullPointerException

Comment: you have used a navigationdrawer in your activitymain.xml .right ?

Comment: yes, I did use NavigationDrawer

Comment: post your xml here .

Comment: @SagarNayak I have posted it